# How to Prevent User from Restarting a Game Until the Day Ends After Completion or Game Over in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a game application where users need to complete certain tasks within a day. Once the game is completed or if it's game over, I want to prevent the user from restarting the game until the day ends, even if they refresh the page. However, currently, even after completion or game over, users can refresh the page and start the game again.

- I'm using local storage to store game state data and check if the game is completed or if it's game over.
- I have implemented logic to update the game state in local storage when the game is completed or if it's game over.
- When the user refreshes the page, the game allows them to play again, regardless of whether the game was completed or game over.

###### Implemented code

```
useEffect(() => {
    checkLocalStorage(store, setStore, data, setData, setGameOver, setGameCompleted);
  },[])
```

```
import { PLAYERS } from "../assets/players"; 

export async function checkLocalStorage(store, setStore, data, setData, setGameCompleted, setGameOver) {
    const fullDate = new Date();
    const date = fullDate.getDate();
    const lastPlayed = localStorage.getItem('lastPlayed');
    
    if(lastPlayed == date){
        console.log('Welcome back');
        const temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stat'));
        if(temp) setData(temp);
        
        const gc = localStorage.getItem('gameCompleted');
        if(gc === 'true') setGameCompleted(true);

        const go = localStorage.getItem('gameOver'); 
        if(go === 'true') setGameOver(true);
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('store')
        localStorage.removeItem('gameCompleted');
        localStorage.removeItem('gameOver');
        localStorage.setItem('lastPlayed', date);
    }
    
    const newData = localStorage.getItem('store');
    if(!newData) return;
    const newStore = JSON.parse(newData);
    setStore(newStore);
}

export async function updateLife(store, setStore) {
    if(store.lives <= 0) return console.log('Game Over');
    const newStore = {...store};
    newStore.lives -= 1;
    await setStore(newStore);
    localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(newStore));
}


export function updateStorePlayer(i, check, key, store, setStore) {
    const newStore = {...store};
    newStore.players[i][key] = check[key];
    setStore(newStore);
    localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(store));
}

export async function checkStat(store, data, setData, setGameOver, setGameCompleted) {
    const newData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stat'));
    if(!newData) return;
    const newStat = {...newData};
    if(store.lives <= 0) {
        newStat.totalGames += 1;
        setGameOver(true);
        localStorage.setItem('gameOver', 'true');
        return;
    }
    if(store.players.every((player) => player.playerName !== '')) {
        newStat.totalWins += 1;
        newStat.totalGames += 1;
        setGameCompleted(true);
        localStorage.setItem('gameCompleted', 'true');
        return;
    }
    setData(newStat);
    localStorage.setItem('stat', JSON.stringify(newStat));
}

export function compare(val, hero, store, setStore, data, setData ,gameCompleted, gameOver, setGameOver, setGameCompleted) {
    const check = PLAYERS.find((player) => player.playerName.toLowerCase() === val.playerName.toLowerCase());
    if(!check) return;
    checkStat(store, data, setData, setGameOver, setGameCompleted);
    let flag = false;
    for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
        if(hero[i].team.toLowerCase() === check.team.toLowerCase()) {
            updateStorePlayer(i, check, 'team', store, setStore);
        }
        if(hero[i].age === check.age) {
            updateStorePlayer(i, check, 'age', store, setStore);
        }
        if(hero[i].nation.toLowerCase() === check.nation.toLowerCase()) {
            updateStorePlayer(i, check, 'nation', store, setStore);
        }
        if(hero[i].playerName.toLowerCase() === check.playerName.toLowerCase()) {
            flag = true;
            updateStorePlayer(i, check, 'playerName', store, setStore);
        }
    }

    if(flag) {
        // incrementLife(store, setStore);
        flag = false;
    } else {
        updateLife(store, setStore);
    }

    localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(store));
}
```

Comment: That seems like an awful lot of code for such simple functionality. Also, you shouldn’t trust client data. What’s to prevent someone from just clearing local storage? Use a server.

Comment: Please reduce your code to an MCVE. You need to set a flag in local storage, and then check that flag when the page loads. A minimal version of this would be only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your mentioned issue, you can have two different solutions.

1. Save your preferred states in your local storage and when pages refreshed, then first check your local storage to see if user have played during the day (to continue) or not.
2. You can put some preferred states in your URL as query parameters which this solution is not as good as the first one.

**And please consider** that by doing these solutions you just handled this problem in **client side** and if you're seeking for more security, definitely you have add a checking in your **server side** of your project with your back-end language.

Hope this description be helpful for you.
Good Luck!

Comment: but there is no user authentication like NYT wordle.
how can i indentidy unique users

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't find any specific solution for this purpose. You know, you should at least have your users data in your DB to identify who is playing. So based on your comment, you just can rely on saving your preferred states (with date) in local storage and retrieve them whenever you need.